# How do I list non-continuous periods of work with the same company on a resume?

Tags: resume, internship

One of the graduation requirements for my degree is to complete 3 co-op rotations (essentially full time paid internships that each last one semester), with an optional 4th. As a result, when I graduate I'll have worked for one company in my field for 2-3 calendar years even though I wasn't working the entire time. When I list this on a resume, should I make a note that it was non-continuous, or just list the years I worked there?

In case it's relevant, my field is computer programming

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would list the non-continuous periods separately, but under the same title/organisation and above the description of the role's responsibilities. It should be clear from your resume that these were internships separated by studies during your degree education.

> Whatever Role Internships
>   AlphaBravo Company
>
> March 2016 to December 2016
>   March 2017 to June 2017
>
> After completing 3 mandatory internship rotations, I was able to retun for an additional 4th some time later. During my time at AlphaBravo I participated in ... and achieved ..., including ...

Answer (score 7):

I generally agree with [HorusKol's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/95501/16983) but wanted to offer another option. I have a similar situation on my resume for two positions: one is a company I interned with for two summers, and another is a campus job that I only had *during* the school year. It looks something like this

> Engineering Intern
>   ABC Company
>   Summer 2016, 2017
>
> Physics tutor
>   State University
>   Five semesters, 2015-2017

I specifically described "summers", or "semesters" for these mainly as a way to make things more compact and concise. Adding "May-August 2016, May-August 2016" is long and somewhat repetitive, and trying to break out every semester for the tutoring job while leaving out long breaks would be even more so. Particularly for internships, most companies know that they only last a few months and don't need to know whether you worked May-August, or June-September.

Comment: Yeah, this also works - but not all summers/semesters are equal (in the UK some universities only have 3x8 week terms instead of 3x10). Also, the"summer" position could be only a week or two or longer. Best to put the time in weeks in brackets.

Comment: @HorusKol If I were comparing two candidates' resumes and one listed an 8 week campus job and another a 10 week, I would view them pretty much equally. And yes, it's not a bad idea to mention the actual length of the internship, particularly if it's non-standard, but what would be more important to me is that the company liked you enough to hire you back a second summer. I guess it's a matter of determining when useful information becomes just clutter, and that will vary from person to person.